# Does glsl texture2d disable blending?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

I try to blend several deformations of a texture, each time in a different color, but the colors are not blended.

When I change only one line in my fragment shader: to use vec4 instead of texture2D, the colors are blended perfectly.

My code:

```
// set color mask to red only
glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_TRUE);
// draw
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, deformation_grid->mesh().triangles().size(),
        GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, deformation_grid->mesh().triangles().data());

// set color mask to green only
glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_TRUE, GL_FALSE, GL_TRUE);
// draw
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, deformation_grid->mesh().triangles().size(),
        GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, deformation_grid->mesh().triangles().data());
```

My Fragment shader:

```
const char fragment_shader[] = "precision highp float;\n"
    "uniform sampler2D u_texture;\n"
    "varying vec2 v_uv;\n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "  vec4 texColor = vec4(texture2D(u_texture, v_uv).rgb, 0.5);\n"
    "  vec4 oneColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5);\n"
    "  gl_FragColor = texColor;\n"
    "}\n";
```

I would expect to always get yellow, but I actually get yellow when I set

```
gl_FragColor = oneColor
```

and green when I set

```
gl_FragColor = texColor
```

Changing the alpha value in glColorMask() and in the fragment shader didn't have any effect.

Does texture2D disable the blending that is set by glColorMask?
If it does, how can I avoid it?

Comment: It shouldn't. But what you're seeing doesn't make sense given what you've told us so far. If `gl_FragColor = oneColor;` gives you yellow, then something else is set up incorrectly. I would expect you to get either white (at 50% transparency) or, given your color mask, red (at 50% transparency). It seems like there's some other state set, but without seeing more of your code, it's impossible to know what.

Comment: What's the content of the texture? You can't necessarily expect yellow unless the values of the R and G components in the texture are the same. Also, you talk about blending. Do you have blending enabled? What's the blend function you are using?

Comment: I use glEnable(GL_BLEND); and glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); to enable blending. I think that yellow makes sense when I use oneColor, because red+green should create yellow. I use a checkerboard pattern as a texture, so I would expect to get yellow in the white squares also when I use texColor.